# How to get the dynamic portion from a nested dynamic url in Next JS app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Say I have a dynamic nested url like this
`abcd.com/[dynamic]/dashboard/settings`
How can I get hold of the `[dynamic]` portion in the `settings` page in the new Next JS app router?

In the previous version this can achieved by `router.query` but in app router I am unable to find similar to this.